# There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

One of our production servers is reporting an error in the log

> Error: 701, Severity: 17, State: 123.
>    There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.

I searched for this error and found it’s a bug and there is a hot fix with service pack 2. These are the server's details:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0  Standard Edition (64-bit)
>   No. of Processors:  24 (with 2 NUMA nodes, each with 12 cores)
>   Memory:  24GB RAM allocated for SQL Server.
>   Query Batchload/Min: 5000+

My questions are

- Why are we getting this error?
- Is it a serious issue?
- How can we resolve?

Edit memory status:

```
MEMORYBROKER_FOR_RESERVE (internal) Pages ---------------------------------------- ---------- Allocations 200362 Rate 4510 Target Allocations 200362 Future Allocations 588626 Overall 2521497 Last Notification 0
MEMORYBROKER_FOR_STEAL (internal) Pages ---------------------------------------- ---------- Allocations 431548 Rate 1973 Target Allocations 323529 Future Allocations 0 Overall 2521497 Last Notification 2
MEMORYBROKER_FOR_CACHE (internal) Pages ---------------------------------------- ---------- Allocations 2356531 Rate 33 Target Allocations 1758664 Future Allocations 0 Overall 2521497 Last Notification 2
Memory Pool (internal) Pages ---------------------------------------- ---------- Allocations 2988441 Predicted 3378711 Private Target 0 Private Limit 0 Total Target 2988441 Total Limit 2988441 OOM Count 21
Memory Pool Manager Pages ---------------------------------------- ---------- Reserved Current 200362 Reserved Limit 200362
Big Gateway (internal) Value ---------------------------------------- ---------- Configured Units 1 Available Units 1 Acquires 0 Waiters 0 Threshold Factor 8 Threshold -1
Medium Gateway (internal) Value ---------------------------------------- ---------- Configured Units 24 Available Units 24 Acquires 0 Waiters 0 Threshold Factor 12 Threshold 110431232
Small Gateway (internal) Value ---------------------------------------- ---------- Configured Units 96 Available Units 94 Acquires 2 Waiters 0 Threshold Factor 380000 Threshold 380000
Optimization Queue (internal) Value ---------------------------------------- ---------- Overall Memory 20656103424 Target Memory 2650349568 Last Notification 2 Timeout 6 Early Termination Factor 5
Small Query Memory Objects (internal) Value ---------------------------------------- ---------- Grants 0 Waiting 0 Available 9391 Current Max 9391 Future Max 9391
Query Memory Objects (internal) Value ---------------------------------------- ---------- Grants 3 Waiting 0 Available 0 Current Max 200362 Future Max 178439 Physical Max 2354504 Next Request 0 Waiting For 0 Cost 0 Timeout 0 Wait Time 0
Global Memory Objects Pages ---------------------------------------- ---------- Resource 24107 Locks 11687 XDES 2058 SETLS 25 SE Dataset Allocators 48 SubpDesc Allocators 170 SE SchemaManager 119635 SE Column Metadata Cache 340416 SQLCache 7683 Replication 4 ServerGlobal 53 XP Global 2 SortTables 3691
Procedure Cache Value ---------------------------------------- ---------- TotalProcs 42635 TotalPages 1237648 InUsePages 46927
Process/System Counts Value ---------------------------------------- ---------- Available Physical Memory 16807735296 Available Virtual Memory 8728772362240 Available Paging File 64584347648 Working Set 29136527360 Percent of Committed Memory in WS 99 Page Faults 134597225 System physical memory high 1 System physical memory low 0 Process physical memory low 0 Process virtual memory low 0
Buffer Pool Value ---------------------------------------- ---------- Committed 3145728 Target 3145728 Database 325288 Dirty 12006 In IO 0 Latched 1 Free 245 Stolen 2820195 Reserved 168246 Visible 3145728 Stolen Potential 0 Limiting Factor 17 Last OOM Factor 0 Last OS Error 0 Page Life Expectancy 126
OBJECTSTORE_LOCK_MANAGER (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 65540 VM Committed 65540 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 93496 MultiPage Allocator 0
OBJECTSTORE_LOCK_MANAGER (node 64) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 24 MultiPage Allocator 0
OBJECTSTORE_LOCK_MANAGER (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 87408 MultiPage Allocator 0
OBJECTSTORE_LOCK_MANAGER (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 65540 VM Committed 65540 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 6064 MultiPage Allocator 0
OBJECTSTORE_SERVICE_BROKER (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 448 MultiPage Allocator 0
OBJECTSTORE_SNI_PACKET (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 39816 MultiPage Allocator 168
OBJECTSTORE_SNI_PACKET (node 64) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 0 MultiPage Allocator 56
OBJECTSTORE_SNI_PACKET (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 19952 MultiPage Allocator 56
OBJECTSTORE_SNI_PACKET (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 19864 MultiPage Allocator 56
OBJECTSTORE_LBSS (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 384 MultiPage Allocator 3312
OBJECTSTORE_LBSS (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 192 MultiPage Allocator 1616
OBJECTSTORE_LBSS (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 192 MultiPage Allocator 1696
USERSTORE_SXC (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 1968 MultiPage Allocator 0
USERSTORE_SXC (node 64) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 8 MultiPage Allocator 0
USERSTORE_SXC (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 1008 MultiPage Allocator 0
USERSTORE_SXC (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 952 MultiPage Allocator 0
USERSTORE_OBJPERM (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 336856 MultiPage Allocator 1536
USERSTORE_OBJPERM (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 31112 MultiPage Allocator 256
USERSTORE_OBJPERM (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 305744 MultiPage Allocator 1280
USERSTORE_TOKENPERM (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 207480 MultiPage Allocator 206976
USERSTORE_TOKENPERM (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 48400 MultiPage Allocator 0
USERSTORE_TOKENPERM (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 159080 MultiPage Allocator 206976
USERSTORE_DBMETADATA (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 4920752 MultiPage Allocator 0
USERSTORE_DBMETADATA (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 134904 MultiPage Allocator 0
USERSTORE_DBMETADATA (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 4785848 MultiPage Allocator 0
USERSTORE_SCHEMAMGR (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 3384592 MultiPage Allocator 875256
CACHESTORE_FULLTEXTSTOPLIST (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 32 MultiPage Allocator 24
CACHESTORE_CONVPRI (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 48 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_CONVPRI (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 16 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_CONVPRI (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 32 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_SYSTEMROWSET (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 158520 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_SYSTEMROWSET (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 4280 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_SYSTEMROWSET (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 154240 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_EVENTS (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 16 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_BROKERTO (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 8 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_BROKERREADONLY (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 80 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_BROKERRSB (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 16 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_BROKERUSERCERTLOOKUP (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 8 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_BROKERDSH (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 8 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_BROKERKEK (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 8 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_BROKERTBLACS (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 344 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_BROKERTBLACS (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 8 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_BROKERTBLACS (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 336 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_STACKFRAMES (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 0 MultiPage Allocator 24
CACHESTORE_STACKFRAMES (node 64) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 0 MultiPage Allocator 8
CACHESTORE_STACKFRAMES (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 0 MultiPage Allocator 8
CACHESTORE_STACKFRAMES (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 0 MultiPage Allocator 8
CACHESTORE_XMLDBATTRIBUTE (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 8 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_XMLDBELEMENT (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 8 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_XMLDBTYPE (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 8 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_VIEWDEFINITIONS (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 16 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_NOTIF (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 16 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_TEMPTABLES (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 2600 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_XPROC (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 184 MultiPage Allocator 0
CACHESTORE_PHDR (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 1790864 MultiPage Allocator 4752
CACHESTORE_SQLCP (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 3956392 MultiPage Allocator 70800
CACHESTORE_OBJCP (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 3957888 MultiPage Allocator 120304
MEMORYCLERK_XE (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 600 MultiPage Allocator 200
MEMORYCLERK_SQLSERVICEBROKERTRANSPORT (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 48 MultiPage Allocator 0
MEMORYCLERK_FULLTEXT_SHMEM (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 576 SM Committed 576 SinglePage Allocator 0 MultiPage Allocator 0
MEMORYCLERK_SOSNODE (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 2489552 MultiPage Allocator 162048
MEMORYCLERK_SOSNODE (node 64) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 8 MultiPage Allocator 2496
MEMORYCLERK_SOSNODE (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 1719152 MultiPage Allocator 35216
MEMORYCLERK_SOSNODE (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 770392 MultiPage Allocator 124336
MEMORYCLERK_HOST (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 112 MultiPage Allocator 64
MEMORYCLERK_XE_BUFFER (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 4224 VM Committed 4224 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 0 MultiPage Allocator 0
MEMORYCLERK_XE_BUFFER (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 1408 VM Committed 1408 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 0 MultiPage Allocator 0
MEMORYCLERK_XE_BUFFER (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 2816 VM Committed 2816 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 0 MultiPage Allocator 0
MEMORYCLERK_SQLQERESERVATIONS (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 1602896 MultiPage Allocator 0
MEMORYCLERK_BHF (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 22080 MultiPage Allocator 0
MEMORYCLERK_BHF (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 21928 MultiPage Allocator 0
MEMORYCLERK_BHF (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 152 MultiPage Allocator 0
MEMORYCLERK_SQLXP (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 16 MultiPage Allocator 0
MEMORYCLERK_FULLTEXT (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 464 MultiPage Allocator 0
MEMORYCLERK_SNI (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 1560 MultiPage Allocator 48
MEMORYCLERK_SNI (node 64) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 0 MultiPage Allocator 16
MEMORYCLERK_SNI (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 752 MultiPage Allocator 16
MEMORYCLERK_SNI (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 808 MultiPage Allocator 16
MEMORYCLERK_SQLHTTP (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 8 MultiPage Allocator 0
MEMORYCLERK_SQLSERVICEBROKER (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 1696 MultiPage Allocator 544
MEMORYCLERK_SQLCLR (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 9518776 VM Committed 63964 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 3136 MultiPage Allocator 63336
MEMORYCLERK_SQLCONNECTIONPOOL (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 4680 MultiPage Allocator 0
MEMORYCLERK_SQLCONNECTIONPOOL (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 2344 MultiPage Allocator 0
MEMORYCLERK_SQLCONNECTIONPOOL (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 2336 MultiPage Allocator 0
MEMORYCLERK_SQLSTORENG (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 719424 VM Committed 719424 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 452968 MultiPage Allocator 184512
MEMORYCLERK_SQLSTORENG (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 18360 MultiPage Allocator 8672
MEMORYCLERK_SQLSTORENG (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 719424 VM Committed 719424 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 434608 MultiPage Allocator 175840
MEMORYCLERK_SQLUTILITIES (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 4280 VM Committed 4280 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 7896 MultiPage Allocator 72
MEMORYCLERK_SQLOPTIMIZER (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 78936 MultiPage Allocator 976
MEMORYCLERK_SQLOPTIMIZER (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 472 MultiPage Allocator 16
MEMORYCLERK_SQLOPTIMIZER (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 78464 MultiPage Allocator 960
MEMORYCLERK_SQLQUERYEXEC (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 181368 MultiPage Allocator 1208
MEMORYCLERK_SQLQUERYEXEC (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 66944 MultiPage Allocator 1176
MEMORYCLERK_SQLQUERYEXEC (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 114424 MultiPage Allocator 32
MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 50364416 VM Committed 25835776 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 0 MultiPage Allocator 424
MEMORYCLERK_SQLGENERAL (Total) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 206648 MultiPage Allocator 58008
MEMORYCLERK_SQLGENERAL (node 1) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 2248 MultiPage Allocator 16
MEMORYCLERK_SQLGENERAL (node 0) KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 0 VM Committed 0 Locked Pages Allocated 0 SM Reserved 0 SM Committed 0 SinglePage Allocator 204400 MultiPage Allocator 57992
Memory node Id = 64 KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 2752 VM Committed 2656 Locked Pages Allocated 0 MultiPage Allocator 2576 SinglePage Allocator 22304632
Memory node Id = 1 KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 62636340 VM Committed 28467016 Locked Pages Allocated 0 MultiPage Allocator 1704904 SinglePage Allocator 22304632
Memory node Id = 0 KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 50560 VM Committed 49168 Locked Pages Allocated 0 MultiPage Allocator 47296 SinglePage Allocator 22304632
Memory Manager KB ---------------------------------------- ---------- VM Reserved 62690740 VM Committed 28519876 Locked Pages Allocated 0 Reserved Memory 1024 Reserved Memory In Use 8
Failed allocate pages: FAIL_PAGE_ALLOCATION 1
AppDomain 45 (mssqlsystemresource.dbo[ddl].44) unloaded.
```

Comment: @Kin, yes fulltext is running

Comment: @AA.SC You might be hitting a bug that is fixed in [`SQL Server 2008 R2 CU4`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982854)

Comment: @Kin, I think we should upgrade our system to service pack 3 as it contain hot fixes for both bug IDs 548996 and 1133952

Answer (score 1):

As was noted in a comment on the question by [Kin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/8783/kin):

Do you have an application that's running full text queries? There is a hotfix for SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2. Have you applied this?

- [FIX: "There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query" error message when you run a full-text query that uses compound words in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 or in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982854)

The fix for this issue was first released in:

- Cumulative Update 9 for SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1
- Cumulative Update 1 for SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 2.
- Cumulative Update 4 for SQL Server 2008 R2.

KB article for the the version you need:

- [Cumulative Update package 4 for SQL Server 2008 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2345451)